# When a annotation is clicked how can I pass data to its view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, annotations

When an MKAnnotation is clicked I need to call a function in its view controller, and pass it two NSStrings contained in the annotation. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign your view controller as the map view's `delegate` and implement

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

`MKAnnotationView` has an `annotation` property that you can use to get your strings.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the annotations are some kind of buttons? In this case, they are the sender of the action -> A reference to the clicked annotation is passed as argument to the called function!

Comment: The annotations are annotation(MKAnnotation) from MKMapView used for the map display